# ng-class not applying with expression

Tags: angularjs

I have a model which is an array of objects

Javascript:

```
$scope.itemClass = [];
// a loop that generates these for each item
$scope.itemClass[someNumberOrString] = {categoryClass: "", otherClass: ""};
```

My style is defined as such: If class is ok, make background color green

```
.ok { background-color: green; }
```

My HTML ties the model to the style

```
<td ng-class="{{itemClass[someNumberOrString].categoryClass}}">Some text</td>
```

When I examine the source, I get this, but my background is not green:

```
<td ng-class="ok" class="ng-binding">Some text</td>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I get the color to apply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-class` already expects an expression, so the double curly braces cause the expression to be evaluated twice. Just write:

```
<td ng-class="itemClass[someNumberOrString].categoryClass">Some text</td>
```

and it should work.